# WL.Server.invokeProcedure calls GET/POST method

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We are using WL.Server.invokeProcedure to call procedure between two Javascript adapters. Basically we are doing adapter mashup.

How Mobilefirst calls WL.Server.invokeProcedure procedure either GET or POST.

```
responseData = WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
    adapter: "ServiceAdapter",
    procedure: "storeDocuments",
    parameters: [params],
});
```

The above code doesn't have method parameter. We are facing issue for large payload where procedure calling fails for large JSON parameter object.

Is there any other way to pass large payload.

Comment: What version of MFP are we talking? How large a payload? KBs ? MB?

Comment: We are using 8.0.0.00-20171109-0349.
Payload size is around 1.2 MB. May i know which method is called internally when we use WL.Server.invokeProcedure

Answer (score 0):

When adapter mashup happens, adapter1 constructs a REST url of adapter2 and fires it. This call will reach adapter2 as if originating from an external client.

You can try out the JNDI property `mfp.adapter.invocation.url` and set a local url here , such that REST call stays internal to the system . This way the calls should execute faster and you should be able to carry more payload.

Set the JNDI property with a locally accessible URL including the context root.

For example:

```
mfp.adapter.invocation.url="http://localhost:9080/mfp"
```

Modify the value to suit your environment.

More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/r_JNDI_entries_for_production.html).